# ImportError when importing function from child, if child is already importing from parent

Tags: python, logging, python-import

I am attempting to import a function **mysub** from a module **scratch_child.py** into a main module **scratch_decorator.py**.

scratch_child already imports a decorator from scratch_decorator so both modules import from each other

I am receiving a 
`ImportError: cannot import name 'mysub' from 'scratch_child'` 
error when executing `scratch_decorator`

If I change the import call in `scratch_decorator` from `from scratch_child import mysub` to `from scratch_child import *` scratch_decorator suddenly works perfectly.

Here is scratch_decorator.py

```
import functools
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from scratch_child import mysub

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-2s %(lineno)-3s %(message)s')
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('test.log', maxBytes=15000000, backupCount=500, mode='w')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)


def my_log(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.info('{} with args: {}'.format(function.__name__,args))
        result = function(*args,*kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper

@my_log
def my_add(x,y):
    return x+y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_add(2,4)
    my_sub(10,4)
```

And here is scratch_child.py:

```
from scratch_decorator import my_log

@my_log
def my_sub(x,y):
    return x-y
```

Comment: Are you sure you have at least an empty `__init__.py`  in your `scratch_child` package? You know that importing all works fine, so you can filter out missing which one or more creates you a problem.

Comment: Yes. init.py in the same folder as both scratch_child and scratch_decorator

Comment: I suspect the issue has something to do with either the logger or the decorator.

Comment: There might be a cyclical dependency hidden down the code, so you might carefully review if scripts in both places don't call each other incidentally. Your logger looks fine as it only uses single import `import logging`, nothing else.

Comment: Looks like you have a cyclical dependency - each package calls each other. To resolve this move your definitions in one place and do it on a way that they get called on non-cyclical manner. If package A imports package B, then package B should not import package A.